# Assign Array in C (array contains a struct type)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, variable-assignment

I get this error  **error: assignment to expression with array typ** when I try this:

```
clients[0].data->bottle = x->bottle;
```

This is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    some_data x;
    uint64_t weight;
    some_other_data_t *data;
} CLIENTS;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t bottle[10];
} some_other_data_t;

some_other_data_t x; 
extern CLIENTS clients[5];

/* some functions that set x correctly... */

clients[0].id = 1;                   // works fine!
clients[0].data->bottle = x->bottle; // does not work :(
```

Why is it so easy to set the id but so hard to set the data ?
I even tried to cast data to char* and use strcpy to set `data` but it doesn't work...
How can I set `data`?

I googled a lot but I didnt find a solution...

Comment: array, unlike a pointer is a physically bound datatype. So you can _fill_ an array, not reassign it, it's been already assigned

Comment: So you may use functions like [memcpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memcpy/) to copy content of `x->bottle` to `data->bottle`

Comment: @user3159253 pointers are the same; the difference is that assignment operator works for pointers but not arrays

Comment: The line above doesn't appear in your code below. And the code below would give different compilation errors than the one you gave (e.g. you are using `x` like a pointer when it is a struct).

Comment: @M.M perhaps I didn't expressed it correctly. I mean: arrays have allocated fixed space and this space can't be "assigned" at once, only "filled" in cycle, while pointers, well, point to an arbitrary location and thus can be reassigned to any other location.

Comment: @interjay I corrected the code snippet. it is now in the code

Comment: This code still wouldn't cause this error but another unrelated one.

Comment: I get a memory access error (german: Speicherzugriffsfehler) when I use memcpy like this:  

    memcpy(clients[0].data->bottle, x->bottle, sizeof(x->bottle));

Comment: @interjay what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean exactly what I said: You obviously didn't test this code before posting it.

Comment: @user3159253 any variable - pointer, array, integer etc. always has the same location for its lifetime. And for all of them, you can change the stored value. Arrays use different syntax for changing the stored value but the basic fact is the same. The stored value of a pointer is the address of another object.  (Avoid the mistake of thinking of the stored value of a pointer as being the value stored in the other object).